# Dynamic join Hierarchical data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, hierarchical

i am researching about Hierarchical data by using ms sql .Here is my db value

```
Parent || Child
Fruit      Red
Red        Apple
Red        Strawberry
Fruit      Yellow
Yellow     banana
banana     papaya
Null       Fruit
```

How can i join the table to become something like this

```
Fruit
   Red
      Strawberry
      Apple
   Yellow
      banana
         papaya
```

It can be more nested . How can i dynamic join the table and show the result at above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably first investigate how you want to store the hierarchy before worrying how to query it (this will be somewhat dictated by your schema/storage structure). There are several common methods for storing category-type (i.e. hierarchical) data:

- Adjacency Lists
- Nested Sets
- Flat tables
- etc...

One of the better single sources of information I've seen is [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database) which has all the detail you could want, as well as links to examples, code samples, etc.  Each has its own pros and cons regarding simplicity, performance, etc.

Cheers,
Dave